# Android - read active wallpaper

Tags: android, wallpaper, android-preferences

I am building an app that makes mass changes to Android phone configuration and saves the current settings. I am trying to find a way to read what is the current wallpaper in use; I'd like to replace it with no wallpaper ( wallpaperManager.clear(); ) and then restore the previous wallpaper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll be looking at [WallpaperManager.getWallpaperInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getWallpaperInfo%28%29)

Comment: Thanks Lie ; This method will only return info for live wallpapers. There is no clear way to get the current wallpaper as set by a call to WallpaperManager.setResource(int resid) nor is there a way that I know of to set a live wallpaper from an App. Any ideas?